Integration of function $ [ \int_{0}^{\pi} |\sin x - \cos x| \, dx ] $
Hey I need to evaluate this definite integral:
$
[
\int_{0}^{\pi} |\sin x - \cos x| \, dx
]
$
Don't really know how to approach this, would glad if someone can show me the way to solve this.
I can't use the identity of sin(x)-sin(b) or sin(x)+sin(b)

If you determine when your function changes sign ($x=\pi/4$), you can split the integral into elementay ones

Have you considered looking at the graph of sinx-cosx and then the graph of |sin x-cos x|? ..... It looks like it's just two regions. For the region on the right, you can just integrate sinx-cosx normally, for the region on the left, flip the function upside down and integrate. voila.

Step 1) Rewrite absolute value:
\begin{equation}
|\sin(x) - \cos(x)| = \sqrt{\left(\sin(x) - \cos(x)\right)^{2}} = \sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}
\end{equation}
Step 2) Get indefinite integral
The integral of $\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}$ has been solved here: $I(x) =  \int{\sqrt{1-\sin2x}} \space dx = \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}(\cos x+\sin x)}{\cos x-\sin x}$ (which is similar to WolframAlpha)
Step 3) evaluating integral $I(x)$ at points of interest, which according to WolframAlpha results in $2\sqrt{2}$

Set the function $f(x)=sinx, g(x) = cosx$,where $x \in [0,\pi]$, then these two functions have the same height at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, that is , $h = f-g =0$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.
So by simple calculation, we see that $[0,\pi]$" />
Now
$\int_{0}^{\pi} |\sin x - \cos x| \, dx
$ = -$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin x - \cos x \, dx
$ + $
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\pi} \sin x - \cos x \, dx
$ = -$[-cosx-sinx]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} +$$[-cosx-sinx]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\pi}$ = -($(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})-(-1-0)$) + $( (1-0) - (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) )$= 2$\sqrt2$
